# What is meaning of 'of' in rxjs observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

getUsers(): Observable <`User[]`> {
    return **of** (USERS);
  }

Comment: Are you asking what it does, or why they called it that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well from the [docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/of.md)

> Converts arguments to an observable sequence.

It basically wraps the array object into the Observable stream.